# How do the Note Apps create and save a note you wrote

Tags: android, file, listview, save

I am working on an app and I basically want to implement some type of function like the note apps do. Basically I have a listview set up that has a link to different xml files. I want the user to have a create new option where they can add some text to an edit text and be able to save the text and add it to the listview I have set up.

My question is how do apps like the Note Pads and Memos ect. do this. Do I need to set up some type of database or?

I have googled it quickly and did a quick search on stack but I don't know if I'm even searching for the right thing. I am just looking for a step in the right direction please!

Thanks!

Comment: There is a notepad demo app comes with Android SDK, you can get the source code.

Comment: yes, they save it in a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They all save their data in a database. For android you should use an SQLite database because it is included in the SDK. There are a lot of great tutorials for SQLite out there, but I think that this is the best one

- http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

It is possible to do this using `SharedPrefernces`, but I would not recommend it, for efficiency and simplicity

Comment: Don't have enough reputation to... but once I do I will thanks very much jcw!